# How to write the data of my entity in my form in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a form in Symfony 2 and what I want is to know if there is a way to write the data of my entity in the field of my form, but I would like to do it inside of my form class.

I know that I could just pass those data to my form from my controller, but since my form knows to which entity it is mapped, I tought that it might be possible to get those info inside of my form and put it in my fields there. My form is mapped to my entity "infos". It as no join and it will always have only one entry in that table, so would just need to get the first entry (if there is at least one).

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

Class ModifierInfosType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $constructeur, array $options)
    {
        $constructeur
        ->add('travailFr', 'text', array(
                                        'label'=>'Travail (Fr)',
                                        //'data'=>'Mes données'
                                    ))
        ->add('travailEn', 'text', array(
                                        'label'=>'Travail (En)',
                                        //'data'=>'Mes données'
                                    ))
        ->add('lien', 'url', array(
                                    'label'=>'Lien travail',
                                    //'data'=>'Mes données'
                                ))
        ->add('linkedin', 'url', array(
                                    'label'=>'LinkedIn',
                                    //'data'=>'Mes données'
                                ))
        ->add('Modifier', 'submit');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Infos',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {

        return 'portfolio_modifier_info';

    }

}
```

My entity:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet Inter
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_infos");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\InfosDepot")
 */
class Infos
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inf_travail_fr", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Poste occupé
    protected $travailFr;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inf_travail_en", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Poste occupé
    protected $travailEn;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inf_lien", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Lien vers l'emploie
    protected $lien;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inf_linkedin", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Lien vers la page linkedin
    protected $linkedin;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set travailFr
     *
     * @param string $travailFr
     * @return Infos
     */
    public function setTravailFr($travailFr)
    {
        $this->travailFr = $travailFr;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get travailFr
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTravailFr()
    {
        return $this->travailFr;
    }

    /**
     * Set travailEn
     *
     * @param string $travailEn
     * @return Infos
     */
    public function setTravailEn($travailEn)
    {
        $this->travailEn = $travailEn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get travailEn
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTravailEn()
    {
        return $this->travailEn;
    }

    /**
     * Set lien
     *
     * @param string $lien
     * @return Infos
     */
    public function setLien($lien)
    {
        $this->lien = $lien;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lien
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLien()
    {
        return $this->lien;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkedin
     *
     * @param string $linkedin
     * @return Infos
     */
    public function setLinkedin($linkedin)
    {
        $this->linkedin = $linkedin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkedin
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLinkedin()
    {
        return $this->linkedin;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that, or should I just pass the info to my controller?

Comment: Pass it in your controller, no need for anything else. This is good practice.

Comment: When you say pass it in my controller, do you mean pas it to my form or to my twig, bacause I could do either

Comment: I assume, you call the createForm method in a controller. If you pass the underlying object to the createForm method, the data of the object will be in the form and therefore preset in your view.

Comment: Yes! It writes the data automatically, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did just like DerStoffel suggested. I passed my entity to my form like this:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AdminBundle\Form\ModifierInfosType;

class InfoController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction(Request $request)
  {
    //Tente de trouver l'enregistrement de la table info
    $infos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PublicBundle:Infos')->find(1);

    //Formulaire pour modifier les infos
    $form = $this->createForm(new ModifierInfosType(), $infos);

    //On surveille le formulaire
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('AdminBundle::info.html.twig', array(
         'form'=> $form->createView()
    ));
  }
}
```